# RingCentral phone application login report

Tags: ringcentral

We are using RC desktop phone app for communicating.
We have different extensions and users in those extensions who are using the app and login into it.
Where can I get those login in and out generated report for audit in the application or admin portal?
We can check users login activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not there in RingCentral as I can see a feature request in Idea portal:

https://ideas.ringcentral.com/ideas/CUSTCOM-I-1909

This feature request will be reviewed by RingCentral and hopefully implement in future version